# htaccess mod-rewrite: link to subdirectory from root - neglect dirs in subdirectory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I asked part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042347/htaccess-routing-to-subdirectory-on-server-performance-loading-tim) a while ago on stackoverflow and this works perfect:
es

I have a multi-domain-server each directory is correspondend to a domain-name. However my main-domain name www.mydomain.com is also a directory on my server and not linked to automatically.

This is why I use this in my root of the website …

### root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-website/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-website/$1 [L]
```

Now when I call www.my-website.com it automatically runs the `/my-website` directory. That's just fine. However in this directory I have another .htaccess file with this in it.

### root/my-website/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/projects/(.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/jobs/(.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(/downloads/.+)/?$ assets/$1 [L,NC]
```

So this means that for this website some links like `/projects/` are just "neglected" and don't actually exist.

However if I run this website now live on my server and due to the main-htaccess file in my root, the RewriteConditions in my sub-directory don't work and I get a "Not found"

How can I make this work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

**DocumentRoot/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^projects/(.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^jobs/(.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(downloads/.+)/?$ assets/$1 [L,NC]

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-website/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-website/$1 [L]
```

**/my-website/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my-website/

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: it worked, however I had to put `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` into the root .htaccess otherwise it wouldn't.

Comment: is it possible that subdomains on my multidomain are not working any longer due to this scripts? "The requested URL /anothersite/.php was not found on this server. this is probably because of my first comment?

Comment: thank you, but does not work for me. If I use your code now the subdomains work again, but in `my-website` no links work without .php extension.

Comment: Actually I am not sure which problem I am solving it now. Would it be too much trouble if you open up a new question and clarify the problem you're facing with the link to this question?

Comment: Well I could. However it's probably a small fix now. The problem I'm facing is, that you're code does what I want by having a root .htaccess file and a /my-website/.htaccess file that don't interfere with each other. However right now my subdomains and other domains in my multidomain-setup don't work any longer cause .htaccess defines that it should call a .php file for every url-entry. E.g. if I enter `something.my-domain.com` it executes `something.my-domain.com.php` it always appends the php extension.

Comment: If you note this condition `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]` ONLY adds `.php` if corresponding `.php` file exists. And there is no scenario where `.php` will be added in front of a domain name.

Comment: Well, I use you're exact code but get this … http://cloud.florianmatthias.com/Z5RB for another domain. Like mentioned above it's a multidomain setup where apart from `/my-website` and the root-.htaccess file are other domains like `/another-domain` -> and this `/another-domain`'s don't work anymore because of this error … http://cloud.florianmatthias.com/Z5RB (the main domain works just fine and exactly how I want it.)

Comment: If `/another-domain/` is a directory then there are 2 conditions that stop it becoming `/another-domain/.php`. 1) `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and 2) `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]` so I am unsure how that can become. Are you sure rules are like this only?

Comment: I made a new question … http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617487/htaccess-on-multidomain-setup-other-domains-dont-work

Answer (score 0):

I was posting this on serverfault, when question was deleted. You already have a working answer, but I thought I'll still post this here, so you can have some explanations about this:

When you have mod_rewrite instructions in a .htaccess in a subfolder, only those instructions will apply, those of the parent folder will not be applied. You can make the rules that are in the .htaccess of the parent folder apply by using the

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

directive in the subfolder. But then it could become a bit messy. And you need to remember that the rules in the parent folder are applied **after** the rewrite rules in the subfolder. Better you go with a solution like proposed in only 1 .htaccess file.

Your 3 last RewriteRule search for a "/" at the beginning, which they never have in a per directory context, but have in a per server context. So if you are in .htaccess file (per dir context) then the comparison is made with a string that has no / at the beginning. See the doc about the [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Comment: is it possible that subdomains on my multidomain are not working any longer due to this scripts? "The requested URL /anothersite/.php was not found on this server.