# htaccess on multidomain setup: other domains don't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a multidomain setup that looks like this on my server … this is a model of the structure:

- .htaccess
- ***my-website

  - .htaccess
  - index.php
  - projects.php
  - jobs.php
  - some-project.php
  - another-project.php
  - some-job.php
  - another-job.php***
- other-domain
- other-domain
- other-domain

### I have two goals:

**1.)** The root .htaccess file should just make sure, that my main-domain which is `/my-website` is run/executed automatically when entering `www.my-website.com`. Due to the fact that I have a multidomain ftp-server I need do specify that. That is working already.

**2.)** In my sub-directory `/my-website` I need some different rules, especially regarding better url design and the omittance of .php extension.

- So in `/my-website` I want to neglect all `.php` suffixes.
- And I want to "fake" directories like `/jobs` `/projects` which are actually not directories but php-files themselves.

This is what I have so far thanks to @anubhava in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607911/htaccess-mod-rewrite-link-to-subdirectory-from-root-neglect-dirs-in-subdirect).

## DocumentRoot/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^projects/(.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^jobs/(.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(downloads/.+)/?$ assets/$1 [L,NC]

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-website/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-website/$1 [L]
```

## /my-website/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my-website/

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

However I have the problem now when using this, that in `my-website` the links without a trailing `.php` wont work. I want my links to work like `/projects` but run/exectute `/projects.php` in my-website. However this doesn't work at the moment, i get a 404.
I also want `/projects/some-project` to run/execute `/some-project.php` (where the `projects` directory doesn't actually exist) which doesn't work either, also 404.

### So, to sum it up.

- All my domains work now! So my multidomain-setup is save and handeld.
- However inside `/my-website` I want all links to work without trailing .php and with this "faked" directories

So right now this works …

- **www.my-website.com** *// works*
- **www.other-domain.com** *// works*
- **www.my-website.com/projects** *// doesn't work without trailing .php*
- **www.my-website.com/projects.php** *// works (runs projects.php)*
- **www.my-website.com/projects/some-project** *// doesn't work (should run some-project.php)*
- **www.my-website.com/projects/some-project.php** *// works (runs some-project.php)*

Comment: Try commenting out last 4 lines of root .htaccess and and then enter: `http://domain.com/my-website/test` to see if that link works.

Comment: @matt Do you have access to the main config file (httpd.conf or however it is called on your setup)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Have root .htaccess like this:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## COMMENT out these 2 rules
# RewriteRule ^projects/(.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]
# RewriteRule ^jobs/(.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(downloads/.+)/?$ assets/$1 [L,NC]

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+/)?([^/]+)/?$ my-website/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-website/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my-website/$1 [L]

# add .php extension 2 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+/)?([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

#### /my-website/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my-website/

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+/)?([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Still on mobile so please excuse typos. So when request is /projects/some-project then /projects should be ignored but if request is for /projects only then it should load projects.php ? What if request is for./projects/some-project/abcd?

Comment: exactly. However `/projects/some-project/abcd` currently doesn't exist, but would be good if it works too, but must not.

Comment: This seems to be doable, will update my answer as soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: sorry, but does not work. same as before. `/projects/some-project` does not work - 404.

Comment: doesn't make a difference. Is the .htaccess inside the /my-website/ dir still the same? Here you see my current uploaded root .htaccess file … https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/2p183p1R3x0117363641/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-24%20at%2009.47.12.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67601/discussion-between-anubhava-and-matt).

Comment: I joined the chat. I now use you're updated code. However in this case wheter `/projects/some-project` nor `/projects/some-project.php` works. But `/projects` works!

Comment: OK some progress. Can you tell me what is correct full path of some-project.php ?

Comment: the full path? it's in root/some-project.php

Comment: but the same problem also occurs with `/jobs` and `/jobs/some-job` … where again the directory `/jobs` does not actually exist but `jobs.php` and `some-job.php` are located in the root directory. Just like projects.

Comment: Right I just wanted to understand whether all the php files are in DocumentRoot or in /mywebsite/ sub directory?

Comment: one moment, sorry, of course inside of /my-website/ … in root there are just the directories of the domains. Inside of `/my-website` this is the case. see my question, where I pointed out my serverstructure. So in root there are only domain-names and the root .htaccess file. Inside of `my-website` there is the .htaccess file and the rest of the .php files, no directories except for `/assets` where css and js is located. But no dir like `/jobs` or `/projects` just plain .php files.

Comment: Then /my-website/.htaccess has correct series of rules. Make sure you replace all those instances of mywebsite with your actual subdir name.

Comment: I did, just tried again with both .htaccess files! In this case `projects/some-project` nor `/projects/some-project.php` work. Not even with .php extension it works. Both end in 404.

Comment: Earlier you said /project is working, it is all very confusing for me. I will have to give up now since these are all working rules in my similar setup as you have described. Only reason I can guess is probably there still are some facts I don't know about your file structure. Or If you can grant a guest access to your sever I will need to check it out to proceed.

Comment: `/projects` is working, I didn't say it's not. But `/projects/some-project` nor `/projects/some-project.php` is not.

Comment: Hey, I updated my question one last time with the exact specifiactions of my server and the .htaccess codes provided by you in the last thread. I exactly pointed out what works and what doesn't - maybe now you can have a look again. thanks.

Comment: now it works, however doesn't without extension. This is not a problem, just wondering why it wouldn't work the regular way if I'm entering `/projects.php`. Thank you anyway, I have now what I wanted.

Comment: You mean `www.my-website.com/projects` and `www.my-website.com/projects/some-project` are still not working?

Answer (score 0):

DocumentRoot/.htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^projects/(.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^jobs/(.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(downloads/.+)/?$ assets/$1 [L,NC]

# add .php extension for REQUEST_FILENAME existing in /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Check if REQUEST_URI is existing as file or directory in /my-website
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-website/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-website/$1 [L]

# Check if REQUEST_URI is existing as file.php in /my-website
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-website/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my-website%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-website/$1 [L]
```

/my-website/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my-website/

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: With this I get a 404 for `www.my-website.com` in general, but `www.my-website.com/projects` works, however `www.my-website.com/projects/some-project` again doesn't.

Comment: The `some-project` thing is new. It's not covered in this rule. Can you please clearyfy where the document root of `www.my-website.com` is? Is it my-website or /?

Comment: This does not answer my questions! Do you want everything rewritten from documentroot to /my-website?

Comment: I want to have my multidomain-server configured to run `/my-website` subdirectory automatically when browsing `www.my-wesbite.com`. This is one part of the deal. The second but for different part is that within the `/my-website` directory I want to omit .php extension and "fake" some directories for better understanding. E.g. I link to `/projects/some-project` event though `projects` is not a directory but a php-file by itself. See again update in my question.